# When does $2^n$ start with n?

Tags: exponentiation, integers

A trick my dad taught me for easily referencing powers of 2 is that $2^6=64$ and $2^{10}=1024$, because $64$ starts with $6$ and $1024$ starts with $10$, and so it's faster than manually doubling numbers if I wanted to find $2^7$ or something quickly in a math competition.

This made me curious to think - does this property that $2^n$ begins with $n$ in its base 10 representation hold for any other $n$'s besides 6 and 10? How about in other bases? What kind of mathematics would this type of problem fall under, and how would one go about solving it?

Comment: $2^{1542}$ and $2^{77075}$ have this property

Comment: What is the significance of this comment, can you tell me @user420261?

Comment: @user170039 Huh?

Comment: I mean why did you write this comment @user420261? Did you have any special intention for writing this (e.g., clarification of any issue(s) that is asked in the question)?

Comment: the binary representation of $2^n$ starts with $n$ whenever $n$ itself is a power of 2

Comment: @user170039 Sorry, I still have no idea why you would ask this.

Comment: Tangent:  I never thought of this.  But how does these make figuring out $2^7$ any easier?  I'm curious.

Comment: More examples found at https://oeis.org/A100129

Comment: I think when n is prime $2^n$  has not this property.

Comment: @fleablood I think the idea is that if you have the sequence $1,2,4,…,1024,2048$  memorized, but you don't always remember which power is which, the $2^6$ and $2^{10}$ help you get your bearings.  Like if you are trying to remember which is the 22nd letter of the alphabet, it helps to have $T=20$ memorized.

Comment: @MJD Yeah.... but the fact that $2^6$ begins with $6$ and $2^10$ begin with $10$ doesn't seem relevent any more than knowing $2^7$ begins with $12$.  Or is it that it's a mnemonic to make remembering $2^6 = 64$ easier than remembering $2^7 = 128$?  I never remembered that that $T = 20$.  That would have helped.  I always used $N = 14$ and $J = 10$ which never helped at all.  But $N = 14$ makes ROT13 coding easier.  Oh, well.  I wasn't criticizing.

Comment: It should be obvious why it would be easier to remember that $2^6$ begins with 6 than to remember that $2^7$ begins with 12.